# Allow user to claim account

Tags: database-design

This is more of a general strategic question than coding - let me know if it's inappropriate here. I'm sure I'll have coding questions once I have a strategy to work from.

I'm creating a php/mysql site that will allow vendors and merchants to create accounts. Because the vendor and merchant accounts will be related to one another I need to allow vendors to create provisional accounts for the merchants and vice versa so that inventory can be assigned to merchants.

If a vendor creates an account for a merchant, what is the best strategy for allowing the merchant to claim the merchant account at a later time?

Constraints:

I don't necessarily want the merchant to be notified when the vendor creates the account (this would might give vendors an opportunity to spam merchants)

I would like the claiming process to be as automated as possible

I've thought about doing something with email addresses, but this would assume that the initial email address given is accurate.

How would I prevent hijacking of unclaimed pages?

I've thought about simply using a separate table for vendor generated merchants and later linking it to the merchant generated account, but this seems inefficient to me - especially when you consider that many vendors would be creating records for the same merchant.

Any input from your experience would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that a vendor can have zero or more merchants, and a merchant can belong to zero or more vendors.

In this case you can approach it as:

a) A directory of vendors and merchants, the accounts are independent of each other

b) Instead of a vendor creating an account for a merchant, the vendor invites the merchant to create an account

c) Allow a vendor to connect with a merchant or vice versa, but the connection must be approved (to prevent spamming)

d) Only when the connection between the vendor and the merchant is made can the assignment and tracking of inventory happen - the inventory tracking is always tied to the relationship between the vendor and merchant

Hope this helps